# Upgraded to PHP 5.5.31 in CentOS and getting warning "Unable to initialize module"

Tags: php, linux, apache, centos

I upgraded my PHP Version to 5.5.31 and received the following warning:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: apc: Unable to initialize module
>   Module compiled with module API=20100525
>   PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
>   These options need to match
>    in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP 5.5.31 (cli) (built: Jan  9 2016 12:08:06)

How do I get rid of it?

I installed the previous PHP version (5.4) like this:

```
# yum remove php-common  
# yum -y install php55w php55w-opcache  
# yum -y install php55w-xml php55w-mcrypt php55w-gd php55w-devel php55w-mysql php55w-intl php55w-mbstring
# /etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Comment: You cannot mix binaries from different PHP versions. Use binaries from the same version.

Comment: As i am new to this, kindly mention which command did I miss or any document to resolve this Error/Warning